# Saving slash-separated texts as categories

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save text separated by \ as a category. I have to save each \ to represent a subcategory. How can I go about this?

```
$cats = "Category \ SubCategory \ SubSubCategory";

$categories = explode ("\\",$cats);

foreach($categories as $category){
    
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `cat` SET 
        name = '" . $category . "', 
        parent_id = '0'
    "); 
}
```

I apply as above, but of course, I cannot give subcategory IDs to the parent_id part.

table

```
id -   name   -   parent_id  -  status - created_at

1  - Category       - 0
2  - SubCategory    - 1
3  - SubSubCategory - 2
```

Comment: Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID of the previous category that was created.

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: @Barmar i using PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ue [`$db->lastInsertId`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) to get the auto-increment ID that was assigned to the last row that was inserted.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO cat (name, parent_id) VALUES (:name, :parent)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $category);
$stmt->bindParam(':parent', $parent);
$parent = 0;
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $parent = $db->lastInsertId;
}
```